# Wordpress custom gallery visibility hidden displaying blank space

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am using foogallery for my gallery page. Clicking the menus corresponding gallery images will display. Initially when i load gallery page there is blank space. when i click the menus then the visible and hidden are working.

Below is my code.

```
<div id="primarygal" class="content-area">
<div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">


 <div class="maincontentgal">
 <div class="leftcontent1">
 <div id="menu-item"> 
   <ul class="ca-menu">

     <li><a class="showSingle" target="1">
       <div class="cacontent">Advertisements</div></a></li>
         <li><a class="showSingle" target="2">
              <div class="ca-content">Books<span class="slashcolor">/</span>Journals <span class="slashcolor">/</span> Newsletters <span class="slashcolor">/</span> Magazines</div></a></li>
         <li><a class="showSingle" target="3"><div class="ca-content"> Brochures</div></a></li>
         <li><a class="showSingle" target="4"> <div class="ca-content">Calenders</div></a></li>
          <li><a class="showSingle" target="5"><div class="ca-content"> Forms <span class="slashcolor">/</span>Letter heads <span class="slashcolor">/</span> Certificates</div></a></li>
          <li><a class="showSingle" target="6"><div class="ca-content"> Greeting cards <span class="slashcolor">/</span> Invitations</div></a></li>
          <li><a class="showSingle" target="7"> <div class="ca-content">Labels <span class="slashcolor">/</span> Posters <span class="slashcolor">/</span> Product designs</div></a></li>
         <li><a class="showSingle" target="8"><div class="ca-content"> Leaflets <span class="slashcolor">/</span> Inserts</div></a></li>
         <li><a class="showSingle" target="9"><div class="ca-content"> Visiting cards</div></a></li>
          <li><a class="showSingle" target="10"><div class="ca-content"> Wedding cards</div></a></li>

       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="rightcontent1">
     <div class="featurette">
        <div class="gallRgt">

          <div id="div1" class="targetDiv" style="visibility:visible;">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[foogallery id="732"]');?>
           </div>
           <div id="div2" class="targetDiv" style="visibility: hidden;">
                     <?php echo do_shortcode('[foogallery id="743"]');?>
           </div>
           <div id="div3" class="targetDiv" style="visibility: hidden;">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[foogallery id="760"]');?>
           </div>
           <div id="div4" class="targetDiv" style="visibility: hidden;">
               <?php echo do_shortcode('[foogallery id="744"]');?>
            </div>
           <div id="div5" class="targetDiv" style="visibility: hidden;">
                <?php echo do_shortcode('[foogallery id="761"]');?>
           </div>
           <div id="div6" class="targetDiv" style="visibility: hidden;">
                <?php echo do_shortcode('[foogallery id="762"]');?>
           </div>
           <div id="div7" class="targetDiv" style="visibility: hidden;">
                   <?php echo do_shortcode('[foogallery id="763"]');?>
           </div>
           <div id="div8" class="targetDiv" style="visibility: hidden;">
                  <?php echo do_shortcode('[foogallery id="764"]');?>
           </div>
          <div id="div9" class="targetDiv" style="visibility: hidden;">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[foogallery id="765"]');?>
              </div>

         <div id="div10" class="targetDiv" style="visibility: hidden;">
                   <?php echo do_shortcode('[foogallery id="766"]');?>
        </div>


     </div>
  </div></div></div>
   </div><!-- #content .site-content -->
 </div><!-- #primary .content-area -->

 <?php
 if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
  ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
         jQuery('.targetDiv').hide().css('visibility','hidden');
         jQuery('#div'+<?=$_GET['id']>.attr('target')).show().css('visibility','visible');
  </script>
  <?php

      }
      ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">

      jQuery(function(){ 

        jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){ 
          jQuery('.targetDiv').hide().css('visibility','hidden');                                   jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show().css('visibility','visible');
    });
});
```

Below is the link 
[http://imanagerprintingpress.com/gallery/][1]
Anybody please help me.

Answer (score 0):

error your code:

you try change

```
<?=$_GET['id']>
```

to

```
<?=$_GET['id']?>
```

Comment: original file it is correct. I think when i aligned ? is missing. Here problem is jquery. Onpageload want to write something. Check this link you can understand the problem. http://imanagerprintingpress.com/gallery/